# Сохранение данных между разными версиями базы

Tags: access

Есть база данных в и её более новая версия с измененными отчётами, запросами, формами, но с абсолютной такой же структурой таблиц. Проблема в том, что актуальные данные находятся в старой версии.

Как полностью заменить данные в новой базе на данные из старой?

Версия Access: 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему разделением на базы на интерфейс и данные.

- [How to manually split a Access database in Microsoft Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304932)
- [Split an Access database](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/split-an-access-database-HA010342026.aspx)